# What is the exact meaning of “ich wäre gern”?

Tags: meaning, subjunctive

In my exercise book I stumbled across this phrase, and the explanation of the subject was quite vague.

> Ich bin stark, aber ich wäre gern stärker.

I am not quite sure which of the following it means:

- > I am strong, but I would like to be stronger.
- > I am strong, but I would be stronger [if I spent more time in a gym, for example].

I would say that the second version is correct, but it is that *gern* word that confuses me.

Can I say the same phrase without *gern*? If I can, how would it sound to a German person? Would there be any difference?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The **gern** is very important.

> Ich bin stark, aber ich wäre **gern** stärker
>   *I am strong but I would* **like to** *be stronger.*

Without the gern, the sentence translates to your second example

> Ich bin stark, aber ich wäre stärker, wenn [...]
>   *I am strong but I would be stronger, if [...]*

Comment: Thanks! It is clear now.

Answer (score 11):

The first version is correct.

> I am strong but I (gladly) would like to be stronger.

or

> I am strong but I wish I could be stronger

The same prase without "gern" has a different meaning and would need a clause explaining in which case you would be stronger:

> Ich bin stark, aber ich wäre stärker, wenn ich nicht so viel netflixen würde.

Answer (score 0):

*Ich wär gern* bedeutet, dass Du Dir etwas wünschst, das Du im Moment nicht hast, beispielweise:
Du bist in der schule, aber Du wärst lieber im Bett geblieben, dann wirst Du sagen:

> Oh, ich wär gern im Bett!

Answer (score -3):

a) Your first translation is roughly correct.

b) Your second translation is not, quite the opposite. *gern*, in my mind, expresses a wish, but an effortless one. Maybe that's my own character and language use shining through, though. At least it expresses at most reasonable effort; at That it's often followed by conjunctive *aber ...*.

c) I'd suspect an influence of *gar*, cp. *so gern* (sehr gern), and *sogar* (... it's complicated, sogar very complicated). It roughly means *total, perfect, complete*. I don't know more to say about this. Why *-n*?

d) Before even opening [DWDS/gern](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gern) I remembered "to yearn for", which appears related. DWDS further mentions "Gier", "Gernegroß", underlining my Ansatz in a).